# "Parser Error: class class_name hide a global script class " when read tres file with flag bundle

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I want to save and load Resource file in godot 4.2, I used resources for that. in main resources i have another resources which is initiated, the issue was when use resourcesaver.save() with no flag_bundle_set the resource inside main resource doesn't write inside .tres file, so i must use resourcesaver.save(ResourceSaver.FLAG_BUNDLE_RESOURCES) to save it. it saves successfully but when I want to load it with resourceloader.load or load I got this error:
"
Parser Error: class  class_name hide a global script class
"
class_name is my resource class which another resource is inside that.
this is my main resource:
"
extends Resource
class_name elm

var level:int = 0:
set(value):
print("VALU IS SET")
level = value
level_changed.emit(level)
get:
return level
var experience:String= ""
signal level_changed

var asghar_2:Resource = asghar.new()

class asghar extends Resource:
var name2:String = "asghar"

"
and this is how i read and write:
"
var error = ResourceSaver.save(a,"user://_myfile.tres",ResourceSaver.FLAG_BUNDLE_RESOURCES)
print(error)

```
var c:Resource 
if(ResourceLoader.exists("user://_myfile.tres")):
    c=ResourceLoader.load("user://_myfile.tres") 
    
print(c)
print(c.level)
```

"

I try load and resourceloader.load or change name of class, but nothing happens

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: It appears that you save you are bundling a copy of the script with the scene, which conflicts with the original when loading. I do not know what would be an approachable solution for this.

Comment: @Theraot, I just resourcesaver.save a resource file. I have a main node which load and save script attached to it